# str_replace wildcard, replacing whole string

Tags: php, str-replace

I am having trouble with str_replace

Example: I have a string that says

```
insert into %table% (%cols%) values (%vals%)
```

I then go through the string and try to replace each wild card but it replaces the whole string.

Comment: show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

try to pass wildcard character only in `str_replace()`

```
str_replace('%', 'with replace str', $str); // will replace only given char
```

for ex:-

```
$str = "insert into %table% (%cols%) values (%vals%)";
$newstr = str_replace('%', '', $str);
echo $newstr; //insert into table (cols) values (vals)
```